# Unable to display my error messages in form validation in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am a beginner in Jquery. I am trying for form validation.every thing is ok. But it is not displaying the messages what i am specifying. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#RegForm").validate( {
        rules:{
            unameTxt: "required",
            pnameTxt: "required",
            pnameTxt2: "required",        
            phnumTxt: "required",
            emailTxt:"required"
        },
        messages: {
             unameTxt: "Please enter Ur Username",
            pnameTxt: "Please enter Ur Password",
            pnameTxt2: "Confirm Ur password",        
            phnumTxt: "Please enter Ur Phone nm",
                 emailTxt:"Enter emailid"
        }

    });
});
```

please help me

Comment: Are you including a validation plugin?

Comment: It really gets under my skin that you repeatedly typed 'Ur'

Comment: ya..i have included it...its displaying the message..."THIS field is required" TO ALL  the fields

Comment: yes..i am using validate.js -@writeToBhuwan

Comment: it should display the error messages which i specified in coding

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you posted.  Show the HTML.

Comment: @writeToBhuwan, although this is a poorly written question with missing code, the OP clearly stated that his specified messages were not displaying.

Answer (score 2):

Every field must contain a corresponding `name` attribute.

If so, your code is working fine without the problem you report.

**Working:  http://jsfiddle.net/6rV9H/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#RegForm").validate({
        rules: {
            unameTxt: "required",
            pnameTxt: "required",
            pnameTxt2: "required",
            phnumTxt: "required",
            emailTxt: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            unameTxt: "Please enter Ur Username",
            pnameTxt: "Please enter Ur Password",
            pnameTxt2: "Confirm Ur password",
            phnumTxt: "Please enter Ur Phone nm",
            emailTxt: "Enter emailid"
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="RegForm">
    <input type="text" name="unameTxt" />
    <input type="text" name="pnameTxt" />
    <input type="text" name="pnameTxt2" />
    <input type="text" name="phnumTxt" />
    <input type="text" name="emailTxt" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```